# How to increment textbox (month)name on button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to increase and decrease a text box name on click button 
[here an image i post to give clarification of what i have to do exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpCYT.png) 
i tried but text value increaseing  but i wana show month name in that text box

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to add your code you tried

Comment: Any code and please add some more clarification to what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with `Array` .create the array for month .And apply the increment and decrements  value with array arguments position.[`Ternary operator`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjluZKz9qDUAhXDt48KHaz7DAUQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FConditional_Operator&usg=AFQjCNEyfU4zvkUJSNIonRwYQ86E1fetTg&sig2=wUXykWzLIc7qcZXMBp6-VA) used for restrict the count below 0 and above 11

```js
var month = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];
 var c =0;
  $('#mins').click(function(){
  c = c-- > 0 ? c-- : 0;
  $('#mnt').val(month[c])
  })
  $('#plus').click(function(){
   c = c++ < 11 ? c++ : 11;
  $('#mnt').val(month[c])
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mnt" value="January">
<button id="mins">-</button>
<button id="plus">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array of month names, a starting variable to represent the current location in the Array, and a variable to hold the input field for the Month:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", 
              "April", "May", "June", "July", 
              "August", "September", "October", 
              "November", "December"];
var currentMonth = 0;
var monthInput = $("#month-input");
```

Now add click events to the + and - buttons. You'll need to add an id attribute to each one.

```
$("#subtract-month-button").click(subtractMonth);
$("#add-month-button").click(addMonth);
```

Finally, your methods to handle the click events.

```
function subtractMonth () {
    if (currentMonth > 0) {
        currentMonth--;
    }
    monthInput.val(months[currentMonth]);
}

function addMonth () {
    if (currentMonth < months.length - 1) {
        currentMonth++;
    }
    monthInput.val(months[currentMonth]);
}
```